# Simple ubuntu kernel module make file error

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to build a very simple kernel module but I get met with this error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.16.14-051614-generic/build M=/home/nanyo/Documents   /ProgrammingEnvs/LinuxKernelDriver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.14-051614-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/nanyo/Documents/ProgrammingEnvs/LinuxKernelDriver/hi.o', needed by '/home/nanyo/Documents/ProgrammingEnvs/LinuxKernelDriver/hi.mod'. Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1852: /home/nanyo/Documents/ProgrammingEnvs/LinuxKernelDriver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.16.14-051614-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

Here is the Makefile:

```
obj-m += hi.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(CURDIR) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(CURDIR) clean
```

Although there are similar errors on stack overflow none of them spcifically say `no rule to target '.../name.o' needed by '.../name.mod'`

I run make like so `~/Documents/ProgrammingEnvs/LinuxKernelDriver$ make`. Attempting any of the proposed solutions from other questions with sudo and experimenting with CURDIR and PWD did not help.

I am running on Ubuntu 22.04 jammy, wiht the 5.16.14 kernel (I have to run this kernel as older ones dont seem to work well with my VERY recent hardware)

I have been trying to compile 15 lines of code for 2 days now, HELP! :)

Comment: Do you have a source file named `hi.c` in that directory?  Note, POSIX systems are case-sensitive so it must be `hi.c` it cannot be `Hi.c` or `HI.c` or whatever.  And, it must be in the current directory (since you use `CURDIR` in your makefile).  If all of that is true, then run `make -d` and see what make is looking for (note, the output will be voluminous: redirect it to a file then search for `hi.o` and see what make says about it.

Comment: I did not, I assumed the output file name could be anything. Feel free to make that into an answer and I will accept it. Once I changed it to reflect my source file's name it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask `make` to build an object file like `hi.o`, it will look to find a source file to build the object file from.  It won't look for any random source file (what if you had 20 source files?  How should it figure out which one you meant?), it will look for a source file based on the name of the object file.

So if you want to compile C code into `hi.o`, make will look for a source file named `hi.c`.  If you want to compile C++ code into `hi.o`, make will look for a source file like `hi.cpp`.  If you want to compile Fortran, make will look for `hi.f`, etc.

Note that Linux systems, unlike Windows and MacOS, use case-sensitive filenames so `hi.c`, `Hi.c`, `HI.c`, etc. are all DIFFERENT files, and `hi.o` will only match the first one.

If make can't find a source file related to the name of the object file, it's not going to say "well, there's just one source file here, that must be what they meant".  That kind of arbitrary behavior is a bad thing in a build tool: make does exactly what you tell it to do, and if it can't it doesn't try to guess what you meant.  It gives you an error, like *no rule to make target 'hi.o'*.

If you wanted to use a different object and source name for some reason you CAN do it, but you have to tell make about it by writing your own explicit rule:

```
hi.o : mycoolfile.c
        <recipe to build hi.o from mycoolfile.c>
```

Since there's no way the kernel build can know what source file name you might choose, you'll have to write these rules in your own makefile.